# Xcode 7.1 - Project runs in simulator but won't archive or run on device

Tags: ios, swift

I've recently performed a swift1.2 to swift2 migration on a project and even though it runs on simulator, it won't archive or run on a device.

I'm currently developping on Xcode 7.1.

When I reach the stage "Copy Swift standard libraries into .app" I get the following log :

> Copying libswiftFoundation.dylib from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos
>   to
>   /Users/ad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-ghobukpaqwtprjdupmqhdhyqcqye/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/project/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/project.app/Frameworks
>   /usr/bin/xcrun '--toolchain'
>   '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain'
>   'bitcode_strip'
>   '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftFoundation.dylib'
>   '-r' '-o'
>   '/Users/ad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-ghobukpaqwtprjdupmqhdhyqcqye/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/project/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/project.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib'
>   xcrun: error: unrecognized option: --toolchain
>
> usage: xcrun [-verbose] [-no-cache] [-kill-cache] [-sdk ]
>   [-log] [-run]  xcrun [-verbose] [-no-cache] [-kill-cache]
>   [-sdk ] -find  
>   *** error: Couldn't copy and strip bitcode /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftFoundation.dylib
>   to
>   /Users/ad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-ghobukpaqwtprjdupmqhdhyqcqye/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/project/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/project.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib:
>   bitcode_strip failed with exit code 64

It might help to note that I have disabled bitcode in the project build settings since it didn't seem useful to my project and would stop the build even earlier.

Comment: and do you get these same errors even after disabling bitcode?  Also, what happens when you clean your project and rebuild?

Comment: The same error happens whether or not bitcode is enabled.

Cleaning and rebuilding doesn't change the outcome of the build : I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated to Xcode 7.2 and it resolved the error.